# Trim does not strip spaces

Tags: php, string, trim

I've read plenty of answers but never found a solution.

**Why doesn't this work with trim?**

```
$test = trim('Whatever this     is');
echo $test;
```

**This work:**

```
$test= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', 'Whatever this     is');
echo $test;
```

**Expected:**

```
Whatever this is
```

Why doesn't the first one work, when the second one does? No strange characters as I write them directly in the PHP code.

*Please don't close this one too quickly*

Comment: First sentence of `trim()` on php.net: **trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string**

Comment: Obviously not intended for viewing purposes only.

Comment: @Daan First sentence was actually "China PHP conference 2016", but yes, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`trim` strips spaces only from beginning and end of a string. Please refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).